# How do I embed dynamic Ruby into webpacker.yml configuration file for setting the server host?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I need to test the app from a mobile phone, and file is checked into Git where other developers access it. How do I dynamically set the host name to the IP address of the server? I tried

`webpacker.yml`

```
development:
  dev_server:
    host: <%= Socket.ip_address_list.find { |ai| ai.ipv4? && !ai.ipv4_loopback? }.ip_address %>
```

It gave the error

```
Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND <%= Socket.ip_address_list.find { |ai| ai.ipv4? && !ai.ipv4_loopback? }.ip_address %>
```

I tried renaming the file to `webpackager.yml.erb` but it gave the error

```
Webpack dev_server configuration not found in .../config/webpacker.yml.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ran into the same issue and embedded Ruby within `webpacker.yml` doesn't appear to be possible.

However, in development mode, you can override `webpack-dev-server` configuration values via environmental variables. Example:

```
WEBPACKER_DEV_SERVER_HOST=example.com ./bin/webpack-dev-server
```

If you're using Foreman, add the command to the relevant `Procfile`, such as:

```
webpack: WEBPACKER_DEV_SERVER_HOST=0.0.0.0 ./bin/webpack-dev-server
web:    rails s -b 0.0.0.0
```

More specifically, for your case, something like:

```
WEBPACK_DEV_SERVER_HOST=$(ruby -e "require 'socket'; Socket.ip_address_list.detect{|intf| intf.ipv4_private?}.inspect_sockaddr") ./bin/webpack-dev-server
```

References:

- [Dynamic port for webpacker-dev-server](https://github.com/rails/webpacker/issues/767)
- [Allow overriding dev server settings using env variables](https://github.com/rails/webpacker/pull/843)
- [Update README.md for ENV vars with dev server](https://github.com/rails/webpacker/pull/880/files#diff-04c6e90faac2675aa89e2176d2eec7d8)
- [Documentation](https://github.com/rails/webpacker#development)
- [Code](https://github.com/rails/webpacker/blob/master/lib/webpacker/dev_server.rb#L59)

Comment: thanks for including links to relevant issues! helps me learn what's going on.